# will_paginate on limite records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a problem to paginate the record that I request from other web service to get data. When i make a request i get some data(not all because if i get all it will be too big) and the total number of records. will_paginate seem can only display the first page and from the second page it show nothing.

```
page  = params[:page]? params[:page]:1
@fields = ConflictCase.get_fields
sites = ConflictCase.get_paging_sites_from_service(10, (page.to_i - 1)) #this will request data from other webservice that I limit only 10 records
@conflict_cases = ConflictCase.transform(sites["sites"], @fields)
@conflict_cases = @conflict_cases.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => 10, :total_entries => sites["total"].to_i)
```

The problem is that i always get only 10 records so it can display on the first page but from the second page it show nothing. I though because will paginate will work on it own to ignore the first 10 records when we move to second page or more.

Have anyone can suggest any idea?
Thank for your help

Comment: Can you find the sql executed in the log? I think will_paginate should return the correct results. There must be something strange.

Comment: On the last code when I use debugger it return empty array for the request on page 2 or 3 or more. I think that may be my data that requested for the server have 10 records and will_paginate consider that 10 records is used only for the first page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect scenario to use the ruby debugger, or spit out to the logger the values during each iteration of your objects.

Firstly I would assume will_paginate isn't the issue, so I would debug to look at the @conflict_cases object and what is being passed into the paginate() function, and the values each time for page and sites['total'].

Comment: On the last code when I use debugger it return empty array for the request on page 2 or 3 or more. I think that may be my data that requested for the server have 10 records and will_paginate consider that 10 records is used only for the first page.